# CSS Sticky header

Tags: html, css, header, sticky

I have added a sticky header to my homepage, however the sticky header seems to be behind the rest of the content on the page, so when i scroll down the page, images and text are on top of the header, is there a way to stop this?

Here is my code:

```
<style>
/* Reset body padding and margins */
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Make Header Sticky */
#header_container
{
    background: #827878;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    height: 60px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

#header
{
    line-height: 60px;
    margin: 10 auto;
    width: 940px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    line-height: 28px;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif;
}

/* CSS for the content of page. I am giving top and bottom 
   padding of 80px to make sure the header and footer 
   do not overlap the content. */
#container
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 80px 0;
    width: 940px;
}

#content
{
}

/* Make Footer Sticky */
#footer_container
{
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

#footer
{
    line-height: 60px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 940px;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>


<!-- BEGIN: Sticky Header -->
<div id="header_container">
    <div id="header">
        Header Content
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END: Sticky Header -->
```

Comment: Something like this? Added z-index:9999 to header container. http://jsfiddle.net/hGYkt/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this code: Add `z-index: 1000` in both `#header_container` & `z-index: 1001` in `#header` styles.

```css
#header_container { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#header {
    z-index: 1001;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, This worked however my menu is the only thing staying on top. here is my menu CSS `menu_sticky {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 top: 200px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1001;
 background: #f9f9f9 url(../images/menu-shadow.png) repeat-x left bottom;
}`

Comment: Why not add `z-index: 2001;` ? It's 1000x better. ; )

Comment: Another thing you could* do... is actually move the header markup to the bottom of the page. Things naturally stack up as you move down through the markup.

Answer (score 1):

Just use z-index parameter.
For example z-index: 2 (present the order of the layer)
It's available only for elements that use position: absolute, relative or fixed

W3schools example:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Sent from iphone

Answer (score 0):

```css
<style type="text/css">
body{
    margin:0px;
    background:#000;
}
.header-cont {
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
}
.header {
    height:50px;
    background:#F0F0F0;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    width:960px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
.content {
    width:960px;
    background: #F0F0F0;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    height: 2000px;
    margin: 70px auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header-cont">
    <div></div>
</div>

<div></div>
```

[Click here to Check this best link for Sticky header using css](http://www.cssreset.com/creating-fixed-headers-with-css/)

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for a solution so that I can use it for my client luckily I found a solution that also works if you are using a WordPress plugin called Elementor inside that container you can put the code which is also put similar to the code below.

```
.sticky-cssSelector-here {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  /* for alignment below */
  align-self: flex-start;
  height: calc(100vh - 45px); /* this is to set a fixed height in different screen sizes and 100 view height for a maximum height of the element */
  padding-top: 100px; // here you can adjust this one as well to make your element viewable
```

Note: the CSS selector is the one you should place inside the element you want to insert.

If that doesn't work you can try this code below:
position: absolute;
z-index:9999;

Answer (score -3):

To your header add:

```
position:absolute;
z-index:9999;
```

This will lift it above everything else

Comment: OP is using a 'sticky' header, `position: absolute;` would break that functionality. They've already got `position: fixed;` so `z-index` is the only thing needed.