# Android Chrome fixed menu popping in and out with url disappearing

Tags: javascript, css, menu, sticky

EDIT: Here's a Youtube video that illustrates my problem:
http://youtu.be/OguwjZR_GdU

On my website [Black Star Opal](http://www.blackstaropal.com) I've been trying to implement a sticky menu, much like this one [Dansk Kids](http://www.danskkids.com.au). I looked at the Dansk Kids website javascript and CSS: there seems to be no javascript involved in their menu (other than the removal of the logo underneath their sticky menu when they scroll). I want my sticky menu to be as smooth as theirs if possible (ie staying flush with the url bar as it pops in and out).

Here's my css for #carttrans, the menu div:

```
position: fixed;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
height: 49px;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
width: 100% !important;
z-index: 10000;
text-align: center;
margin-left: 0px;
padding-left: 7px;
border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
border-left: none;
border-right: none;
border-bottom-style: solid !important;
border-bottom-width: 1px !important;
border-bottom-color: rgb(221,221,221) !important;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

I also use this js code (only because the menu wouldn't display on iOS Safari without it, although I'm unsure why):

```
$(function() {
// grab the initial top offset of the navigation 
var sticky_navigation_offset_top = $('#carttrans').offset().top;

// our function that decides weather the navigation bar should have "fixed" css position or not.
var sticky_navigation = function(){
var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop(); // our current vertical position from the top

if ($(window).width() < 500)
{
  // if we've scrolled more than the navigation, change its position to fixed to stick to top, otherwise change it back to relative
  if (scroll_top > sticky_navigation_offset_top) { 
  $('#carttrans').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':0, 'left':0 });
  } else {
  $('#carttrans').css({ 'position': 'fixed' }); 
  }   
}
};

// run our function on load
sticky_navigation();

// and run it again every time you scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
  sticky_navigation();
});
});
```

I even removed all the elements in the menu and just left the blank white bar there to see if it would do the same thing. It popped in and out awkardly just like before.

Any help with this would be amazing.

EDIT: As I said below, it's the URL bar popping in and out that seems to be disturbing my sticky menus. It could possibly be a repaint issue or slow down, because on other sites the disappearance of the url bar and the subsequent movement of the menu (for example, on sticky menu demos) is quite smooth and I'm doing/have tested them with the same url bar popping.

Cheers,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<header><h1>Sticky Header</h1></header>
<img src="large-image.jpg" width="782" height="2000" alt="Big Image" />
```

jQuery (remember to include the jquery library)

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){  
     $('header').addClass("sticky");
  }
  else{
    $('header').removeClass("sticky");
  }
});
```

CSS:

```
header{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 72px;
  line-height: 108px;
  height: 108px;
  background: #335C7D;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}
header.sticky {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  background: #efc47D;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
```

REFERENCES:
http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2014/05/how-to-create-an-animated-sticky-header-with-css3-and-jquery/

PREVIOUS SAME QUESTION ON STACK OVERFLOW:
[CSS Sticky header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826610/css-sticky-header)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have tried both of the methods in the above links and they did not work. I spent about a day researching methods on here and on Google and trying them out. I understand the need for a normal class and a sticky class, but I thought that the normal class was absolute or relative main position and that the sticky class then turned into a fixed class. 

I have my menus being sort of sticky, but they're not staying flush with the URL box as it appears and disappears. That's was my question and I'm trying to learn why it's not working.

Comment: Oh. also. when I shrink my desktop browser the fixed positioning works extremely well. It's just the url bar that seems to make it pop up and down on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I used firebug for firefox and just added the following to your #carttrans ID i am assuming you only want this to stick? If so check the css below replace your #carttrans with the below and lemme know if that is what you want?

```
#carttrans {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: right;
    top: 40px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Thanks again, Bryan, but that also didn't work. Here's a Youtube video that shows you my exact problem. Note the menu bar popping up and down and not saying flush with the URL bar of the application.

http://youtu.be/OguwjZR_GdU

Answer (score 0):

Hi i looked at your youtube clip and i see that it could be that the jquery you are using is affecting your main div for the top section #carttrans make sure on this div that your css is marked as important for the top 0px !important so that the jquery won't be able to change it have a try and see if this works?