# How to create a sticky radio player in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am a beginner coder and I need your help.

I need to create a sticky radio station player like this example:

http://rareradio.ancorathemes.com/radio-two/

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS Sticky header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826610/css-sticky-header)

Answer (score 0):

Put your player in a div and give it the following properties in css

```
position: sticky;
top: 50px;
```

Example :

```
<div class="player-sticky">
Player code.....
</div>

css:
player-sticky:{
position: sticky;
top: 50px;
}
```